# How to make the camera follow the mouse in first or third person camera

Tags: unity

I currently I have a game made of a few small scripts, the `PlayerController`, `PlayerStats`, and `CameraChange` (each below).

My question is how do I get the camera to follow the mouse movement? I want the player to be able to switch between each camera and look around with the mouse.

Any idea as to how I'd go about doing this? My current theory is I would some how have to access the current active camera and make it follow the mouse but not sure how to do that.

PlayerController-

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerContorller : MonoBehaviour

{

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        var x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * 150.0f;

        var z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * 3.0f;

            transform.Rotate(0, x, 0);
        transform.Translate(0, 0, z);
    }
}
```

PlayerStats-

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerStats : MonoBehaviour {

    public int Health = 100;
    public int Stamina = 100;
    public int magic = 100;



    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        //if ()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

CameraChange-

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraChange : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject ThirdCam;
    public GameObject FirstCam;
    public int CamMode;


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {



        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Camera"))
        {
            if (CamMode == 1)
            {
                CamMode = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                CamMode += 1;
            }
            StartCoroutine(CamChange());
        }
    }
    IEnumerator CamChange()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.01f);
        if(CamMode == 0)
        {
            ThirdCam.SetActive(true);
            FirstCam.SetActive(false);
        }
        if(CamMode == 1)
        {
            FirstCam.SetActive(true);
            ThirdCam.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The web is littered with beginner Unity tutorials including camera controls. I'd strongly recommend working through one or two of those, or inspecting the standard components provided by Unity in their example projects, rather than rehash it from first principles here, again. Once you've got the basics, you can ask here about specific parts you don't understand, or about how to change particular behaviours that aren't yet working the way you want.

Comment: You should have separate camera scripts, each one for a different type of camera movement. After that you can easily reference them and switch between them. An active camera would be - CameraController, for example. FPCameraController : CameraController and TPCameraController : CameraController. Thus you can set the active camera to either one of them. Now you can disable behaviours on 1 camera or have 2 separate cameras. But it's better that you first create 2 camera behaviours separately and see what they have in common and what would every camera have in common.

Comment: Ok so if i'm reading this right your saying make two separate cameras.Camera 1 and camera 2 then make each have there own script and connect these two separate cameras with a single script that allows me to switch back and forth between the cameras? That's something I don't get why do that? the script I have allows me to switch back and forth between cameras all in one script it already disables the camera component not in use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a new script called `MouseLookAt` and attach it to each camera that the player can "take control of" and look through.

This script determines whether or not its currently being controlled, and if so, takes in the mouse input and translates it into a rotation, applying that rotation value to the object the script is attached to.

In doing it this way you:

1. Get the behavior you want
2. Don't need to reference the camera from somewhere else
3. Have infinite extendability (no matter how many cameras you add, you don't have to change anything)

The "translate mouse into rotation" is very common and easy to find ([here's one](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SmoothMouseLook)), but you'll have to modify it to handle the "is the player currently using this camera" part yourself, as  its not a generic problem.

One option is to keep the script disabled, then when the player selects a new camera:

1. disable the mouse look script on the current camera (if any)
2. get the new camera
3. enable the mouse look script on that camera (`cam.GetComponent<MouseLookAt>().enabled = true`)
4. set the camera as the current camera

You're likely already doing step 2 anyway.

Comment: Thank you this will help further my education into understanding game code it's good to know i was on the right track with my thought process.

Comment: Hey thanks again I don't know how I hadn't figured out what you were saying sooner it was totally simple you were correct simply attaching the look at script to both cameras since on will be disabled when the other activates it will disable the script on it. I have run into two new rather complex problems but I cant figure out if its just me and that's how the cameras are suppose to function or if they still need tweaking to act as I exactly want them to. regardless thanks again you answer worked exactly right with the question and scripts presented for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

This is script to switch between cameras. Everytime left mouse-button is clicked, `myInt` +1. Camera with index `myInt` in the list is then activated, with others deactivated. When `myInt` exceeds `List.Count`, `myInt` is then reset back to 0;

```c#
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MyCameraController : MonoBehaviour {       
    [SerializeField]
    private List<Camera> myList;

    public Transform activeCamTransf;

    private int myInt;

    private void Update () {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
            ActivateCam (SwitchMyInt ());
        }
    }

    private int SwitchMyInt () {
        if (myInt < myList.Count - 1) {
            myInt += 1;
        } else {
            myInt = 0;
        }
        return myInt;
    }

    private void ActivateCam (int i) {
        if (i < myList.Count) {
            myList [i].enabled = true;
            activeCamTransf = myList [i].transform;

            foreach (Camera camTemp in myList) {
                if (camTemp != myList [i]) {
                    camTemp.enabled = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

This is script to rotate the active camera. Rotation is achieved by accumulating X and Y axis of the mouse, then applying it to the `EulerAngle` of the `Transform` of the `GameObject`.

```c#
using UnityEngine;

public class CamRotationController : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeFiled]
    private MyCameraController myCameraController;

    [SerializeField]
    private float speedX;

    [SerializeField]
    private float speedY;

    private float x;
    private float y;

    void Update () {
        x += speedX * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * Time.deltaTime;
        y -= speedY * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * Time.deltaTime;

        myCameraController.activeCamTransf.eulerAngles = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to ask. why did you make the camera change script the way you did does using this "List" make it more efficient? As far as I can tell your script does the same thing mine already does, but it's just longer am I missing a piece of the puzzle as to why you did it that way or were you simple trying to help me learn a new way to achieve this out come? regardless you've given me a new type to look up so thank you lets hope i can figure it out easily ^.^ I also haven't checked  your other script yet, but when i do if it work i guess you'll have the correct answer.

Comment: Hi I tried your script and sadly couldn't make heads or tails of it. Every time I tried to play it through a null reference at me the error involved this line "myCameraController.activeCamTransf.eulerAngles = new Vector3(x, y, 0);" you got me with this one as I have no idea what could be going on as far as I can see the scripts are correct but simply aren't running right. Another error I was receiving was with "[SerializeField]" on the CamRotationController script any idea why it would throw these errors at me?

Comment: If you haven't figured it out already, by using list and utilizing loop, you can have as many cameras to be switched between. In contrast, the method used in your script can only manage so many cameras before it becomes convoluted, and furthermore, you need to modify your script if you want to add or subtract cameras.

Comment: Using `SerializeField` is just a good practice. Usually, you don't need your variables to be public if you don't need them to be accessible by other classes. You need to use `SerializeField` since private variable's value isn't changeable in the inspector.

Comment: I just tested the scripts and notice there are two small problems, but they are easily resolvable. Other than that, the scripts work as intended.

Comment: Oh, I just realized. For this to work, you need to tag all of your cameras with `MainCamera`

Comment: Hey momo so I've learned a ton from this so thanks. However I still can't seem to get it to work I just tried for the first time since doing some research and stuff here is were I'm at currently. error - NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
CamRotationController.Update () (at Assets/CamRotationController.cs:22)
I think the cam rotation script is looking for a reference no idea what to use for that also I messed around a bit and put the player as reference clicking with left mouse button allowed for camera switching but not looking around any ideas?

Comment: Create an empty gameobject in the scene, then attach those two scripts to the gameobject. Assign the gameobject itself to the myCameraController variable. Then, create a bunch of cameras in the scene and assign those cameras to the myList variable. You also need to change the speed of the camera rotation (variable x and y). Voila!

Comment: ok having played around a bit and getting a lot of laughs I figured out the proper place for everything thanks to your last comment. however now I'v found two problems which I think you actually mentioned before and those are that my arrow causes the camera to look in the wrong directions and example would be moving it right and looking down the second issue is that when you start playing you must first switch cameras before it lets you look around. thoughts? the more I mess with this script the more I'm coming across chances to learn I'll look forward to picking this apart after it's all done

Comment: also not entirely sure this is a problem or not but in third person when the character turns the camera just kinda lags behind in a weird way idk that could just seem weird right now because of the look around thing. I can't remember if other games like skyrim function in third person like this I'll have to take a look a try to remember.